# Search and Find through a list Python

Tags: python, list, iteration, tuples

I have a main text file that looks like this:

```html
STATUS| CRN| SUBJECT| SECT| COURSE| CREDIT| INSTR.| BLDG/RM| DAY/TIME| FROM / TO| 
OPEN| 43565| ACA6202| 10| Acting II| 3.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43566| ACA6206| 10| Topics:Classical Drama/Cult II| 2.00| Jacobson, L| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43567| ACA6210| 10| Text II| 2.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43568| ACA6212| 10| Voice and Speech II| 3.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43569| ACA6216| 10| Movement II| 2.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43570| ACA6220| 10| Alexander Technique II| 2.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43571| ACA6224| 10| Stage Combat II| 2.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 43572| ACA6228| 10| Practicum IV| 3.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15| 
OPEN| 44500| ACA6595| 10| Selected Topics| 1.00| Logan, G| SEE DEPT| | 01/12/15 - 04/27/15|
```

My code below gathers only the "SUBJECT" column and strips the numbers from the string. So for example, the output from the top of the file would print several "ACA"s.

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", "r") as myfile:
subsAndAbrevsMap = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", 'r'))

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
masterSchedule = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", 'r'))


for masterline in masterSchedule:
    masterline.strip()
    masterSplitLine = masterline.split("|")

    if masterSplitLine[0] != "STATUS":
        subjectAbrev = ''.join([i for i in masterSplitLine[2] if not i.isdigit()])
```

I have another .txt file that looks like this:

```html
Academy for Classical Acting,ACA
Accountancy,ACCY
Africana Studies,AFST
American Studies,AMST
Anatomy & Regenerative Biology,ANAT
Anthropology,ANTH
Applied Science,APSC
Arabic,ARAB
Art/Art History,AH
Art/Fine Arts,FA
Astronomy,ASTR
Biochemistry,BIOC
Biological Sciences,BISC
```

In my code below, I check to see if the abbreviations(column 2) in my second .txt equal the abbreviations generated from my first .txt document. If it is a match I would like to append the full class name:

```
#open 2nd .txt, strip and split
for subsline in subsAndAbrevsMap:
            subsline.strip()
            subLineSplit = subsline.split(",")
            print "subLineSplit is: " + subsline[0]

            if subLineSplit[1] == subjectAbrev:
                realSubjectName = subLineSplit[0]
                print "The subject name for abrev " + subjectAbrev + " is " + realSubjectName
```

I want the output to print:

```
"The subject name for abrev ACA is Academy for Classical Acting"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: A **lot** of useless `subLineSplit is: A`, I'm sure, due to that weird first `print` emitting the first character of each `subsline`.  But apart from that one weird `print` it seems OK!

Comment: Note that `subsline.strip()` has absolutely no observable effects.  Strings are immutable: calling on a string a method such as `strip` **returns** a copy the string w/o leading and trailing whitespace -- but you're completely ignoring the returned value, and apparently assuming this somehow changes the string in-place (it won't: strings are immutable!).

Comment: can u tell what is subsAndAbrevsMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, these are csv files, so use your `csv` module!

```
# path to first file is ~/classes.csv
# path to second file is ~/abbr.csv

import csv

with open("~/classes.csv", 'rU') as classes_csv,\
     open("~/abbr.csv", 'rU') as abbr_csv:
    classes = csv.reader(classes_csv, delimiter='|')
    abbr = csv.reader(abbr_csv, delimiter=',')
    header = next(classes)

    abbr_dict = {line[1].strip():line[0].strip() for line in abbr}
    # create a lookup dictionary for your tags -> names

    class_tags = (line[2].strip("0123456789 ") for line in classes)
    # create a genexp for all the extant tags in ~/classes.csv

    result = {tag:abbr_dict[tag] for tag in class_tags if tag in abbr_dict}
```

Then it should be easy to format your result.

```
for abbr,cls in result.items():
    print("The abbreviation for {} is {}".format(cls,abbr))
```

Comment: this is the error I get when I run your code: "abbr_dict = {line[1].strip():line[0].strip() for line in abbr}
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?"

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty ah because you're opening it on *nix not Windows. I'll edit, but change the open modes to `'rU'` in both cases.